# Google advanced marker animation don't work

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-api, migration, google-maps-markers

I'm trying to migrate my custom map markers to the new advanced marker library, seems the animation options is no more available, it give me this error:

Unknown property 'animation' of AdvancedMarkerElement

I checked the documentation and the animation options is still there but nothing is mentioned about how to migrate the animation option.

[google marker documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker?hl=it#Animation)

```
newMarker = new google.maps.marker.AdvancedMarkerElement({
    position: markerOpposto,
    map: map,
    content: imageIcon,
    title: "New position",
    animation: google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE 
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use CSS animation for Advanced Markers

First thing that we need to understand about **Advanced Marker** is that it is no longer an **MVC Object** unlike the [Legacy Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/marker#Animation:%7E:text=This%20class%20extends%20MVCObject). The `Animation constants` (`BOUNCE` and `DROP`) that existed on the Legacy Marker are no longer available.

That is because, as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/advanced-markers#:%7E:text=gmp%2Dadvanced%2Dmarker%3E-,This%20class%20extends%20HTMLElement.,-This%20class%20implements), the Advanced Marker class now extends `HTMLElement`. This means that to animate the Advanced Marker, you should use CSS animation now to be able to do so as presented in their Advanced Marker sample here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/advanced-markers-animation

With that said, to reproduce a somewhat similar bounce animation, you first need to define a `.bounce`(You can name this whatever you want) class inside your CSS using keyframes and transform:

```
.bounce {
    animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    -moz-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    -o-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0);} 
    40% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);}
    60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);}
}
 
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-moz-transform: translateY(0);}
    40% {-moz-transform: translateY(-30px);}
    60% {-moz-transform: translateY(-15px);}
}
 
@-o-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-o-transform: translateY(0);}
    40% {-o-transform: translateY(-30px);}
    60% {-o-transform: translateY(-15px);}
}
@keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {transform: translateY(0);}
    40% {transform: translateY(-30px);}
    60% {transform: translateY(-15px);}
}
```

Then inside your map initialization function, you can just add the class `.bounce` to your marker element by using this code:

```
marker.content.classList.add("bounce")
```

Then the animation should work.

Here's a proof of concept snippet for you to check:

```js
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */
async function initMap() {

  // Request needed libraries.
  const { Map } = await google.maps.importLibrary("maps");
  const { AdvancedMarkerElement } = await google.maps.importLibrary("marker");
  // initialize the map
  const map = new Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: 37.4239163, lng: -122.0947209 },
    zoom: 14,
    mapId: "4504f8b37365c3d0",
  });
  // initialize the marker
  const marker = new AdvancedMarkerElement({
    map,
    position: { lat: 37.4239163, lng: -122.0947209 },
  });
  // add the class "bounce" for your css configuration to apply
  marker.content.classList.add("bounce")
}



initMap();
```

```css
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */
/* 
 * Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div element
 * that contains the map. 
 */
#map {
  height: 100%;
}

/* 
 * Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. 
 */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/* Define the bounce animation configuration here */
.bounce {
    animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    -moz-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
    -o-animation: bounce 2s infinite;
}
 
@-webkit-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-webkit-transform: translateY(0);} 
    40% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-30px);}
    60% {-webkit-transform: translateY(-15px);}
}
 
@-moz-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-moz-transform: translateY(0);}
    40% {-moz-transform: translateY(-30px);}
    60% {-moz-transform: translateY(-15px);}
}
 
@-o-keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {-o-transform: translateY(0);}
    40% {-o-transform: translateY(-30px);}
    60% {-o-transform: translateY(-15px);}
}
@keyframes bounce {
    0%, 20%, 50%, 80%, 100% {transform: translateY(0);}
    40% {transform: translateY(-30px);}
    60% {transform: translateY(-15px);}
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<!--
 @license
 Copyright 2019 Google LLC. All Rights Reserved.
 SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
-->
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Default Advanced Marker</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- prettier-ignore -->
    <script>(g=>{var h,a,k,p="The Google Maps JavaScript API",c="google",l="importLibrary",q="__ib__",m=document,b=window;b=b[c]||(b[c]={});var d=b.maps||(b.maps={}),r=new Set,e=new URLSearchParams,u=()=>h||(h=new Promise(async(f,n)=>{await (a=m.createElement("script"));e.set("libraries",[...r]+"");for(k in g)e.set(k.replace(/[A-Z]/g,t=>"_"+t[0].toLowerCase()),g[k]);e.set("callback",c+".maps."+q);a.src=`https://maps.${c}apis.com/maps/api/js?`+e;d[q]=f;a.onerror=()=>h=n(Error(p+" could not load."));a.nonce=m.querySelector("script[nonce]")?.nonce||"";m.head.append(a)}));d[l]?console.warn(p+" only loads once. Ignoring:",g):d[l]=(f,...n)=>r.add(f)&&u().then(()=>d[l](f,...n))})
        ({key: "AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk", v: "weekly"});</script>
  </body>
</html>
```